# How can you disable blog comments in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

How can you disable blog comments in Orchard CMS?  I can't see how to do this. There's nothing about disabling comments in settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add control functionality on your site by enabling and disabling features exposed by the modules that are installed to Orchard. To view the available features, click Features under the Modules heading in the Orchard admin panel.

[image]

I think you will have one called Orchard.Comments

To disable the feature, simply click Disable for that feature.

Also, you can modify the page content type in Orchard to not allow comments.

Log in as an administrator and then head over to the Admin Dashboard.  On the left hand navigation, select the Content item.

[image]

Then click on the Content Types tab at the top.

[image]

Find the Page Content Type and click the edit link.

[image]

Click the Add Parts button.

[image]

And then uncheck the Comments part check box.

[image]

Click Save on this page and then Save again on the Page content type.

Also, when you create a new Page in your Orchard site you will see the Allow new comments check box so that your users can leave comments on the page/article that you create.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very quick and comprehensive answer!